# How to replace all occurrences inside an object?

Tags: javascript, object, replace

I have an object like this:

```
users = [{
  "userid": "1",
  "fornonmods": "<div id=\"user1\" data-login=\"\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">",
  "formods": "<div id=\"user1\" data-login=\"\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">"
}, {
  "userid": "19917",
  "fornonmods": "<div id=\"user19917\" data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">",
  "formods": "<div id=\"user19917\" data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">"
}];
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of
`data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\"`
with
`data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"gagged\"`
just like I would do with `replace()` but the thing is that that only works with strings and I am not allowed to convert this object into a string.
What can I do in this cases?

Comment: so loop over the array and replace the strings. users.forEach

Comment: care to elaborate a little more please?

Comment: @CainNuke you don't want to "replace anywhere in object", but in each `.fornonmods` property of the objects in the array. You know how to iterate an array?

Comment: not only in fornonmods but also in formods and all others i didnt include for the sake of convinience.

Comment: @CainNuke But surely not in userids? So list the properties explicitly that you want to process.

Comment: Use for each loop, reference the property of the object and run your string replace lines

Comment: what do you mean by `I am not allowed to convert this object to a string.` ? is someone watching you closely? Are you being persecuted?

Comment: it means I cant because it will break the whole code.

Comment: I don't understand, you have a computer capable of breaking the text of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is what you're looking for

```js
const users = [{
  "userid": "1",
  "fornonmods": "<div id=\"user1\" data-login=\"\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">",
  "formods": "<div id=\"user1\" data-login=\"\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">"
}, {
  "userid": "19917",
  "fornonmods": "<div id=\"user19917\" data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">",
  "formods": "<div id=\"user19917\" data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\" class=\"item\">"
}];

const id = "kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD";

const res = users.map(x => {
   const container = {};

   container.userid = x.userid,
   container.fornonmods = x.fornonmods.replace(`data-login=\"${id}\" data-status=\"online\"`, `data-login=\"${id}\" data-status=\"gagged\"`);
   container.formods = x.formods.replace(`data-login=\"${id}\" data-status=\"online\"`, `data-login=\"${id}\" data-status=\"gagged\"`);

   return container;
});

console.log(res);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Can I also use a variable for kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD?

Comment: Yes, just use template literals my friend. `string text ${yourVar} string text`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I changed the answer for your request with a const id (kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD)

Comment: it works, thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome my friend

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `users` and replace with `regex` pattern.

```js
const searchString = new RegExp('data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"online\"', 'g');
const replacement = 'data-login=\"kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD\" data-status=\"gagged\"';
const parsedUsers = users.map(x=>{
  return {
    userid: x.userid,
    fornonmods: x.fornonmods.replace(searchString,replacement),
    formods: x.formods.replace(searchString,replacement)
 }
})
```

Comment: great, but can I use also a variable instead of kBr4pelyDy4yKVmiAAAD?

Comment: Of course, just use string concatenation.    `const searchString = new RegExp(`data-.... ${variable}... `, 'g')`°

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.